# browserify with angular: cannot add restangular dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify, restangular

I use browserify to maanger my angular dependencies and it works, but as soon as I want to add restangular I get " Uncaught Error [$injector:modulerr] ".

my package.json looks like:

```
 "browser": {
    "angular": "./public/scripts/angular-index.js",
    "angular-route": "./public/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js",
    "lodash": "./public/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js",
    "restangular": "./public/bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.min.js"
  }
```

and my app.js:

```
 var angular = require('angular');
    require('angular-route');
    require('lodash');
require('restangular');

    var app = angular.module('pocApp', ['ngRoute', 'schemaForm', 'restangular']);

    require('./services');
    require('./controllers');
    require('./app.routes.js');
```

lodash and restangular are included in my generated js

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing `require('restangular');` before `var app = ..`

Comment: Sorry, forgot that line in my paste.
I have it inside my source but it's not working. that's the strange thing about it